# Failed assertion of grid creation in Metal

Tags: c, swift, parallel-processing, apple-m1, metal

I'm trying to adapt [text](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/performing_calculations_on_a_gpu) the example code of parallel sum of vectors using Metal API for Swift/C in order to do a matrix sum.
This block of code manages the size of the Grid and the Groups.
The matrices A,B and Result are [rowsLength,colsLength] big, then distributed on a 1D GPU buffer of rowsLength*colsLength*sizeof(float).
I read the documentation but I haven't found a similar code.
Compiling it I get the error: failed assertion `component 1: 2 must be <= 1 for index [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]' on the last command that dispatch the Threads and also there I have found only 1 question answered but that didn't helped my understanding the problem.

At this point I kindly ask clarification on the computeEncoder and this error.
Thanks

```
- (void)encodeAddCommand:(id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder>)computeEncoder {

    // Encode the pipeline state object and its parameters.
    [computeEncoder setComputePipelineState:_mAddFunctionPSO];
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:_mBufferA offset:0 atIndex:0];
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:_mBufferB offset:0 atIndex:1];
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:_mBufferResult offset:0 atIndex:2];

    MTLSize gridSize = MTLSizeMake(rowsLength*colsLength, 1, 1);

    // Calculate a threadgroup size.
    NSUInteger threadGroupSize = _mAddFunctionPSO.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup;
    if (threadGroupSize > rowsLength)
    {
        threadGroupSize = rowsLength;
    }
    MTLSize threadgroupSize = MTLSizeMake(threadGroupSize, threadGroupSize, 1);

    // Encode the compute command.
    [computeEncoder dispatchThreads:gridSize
              threadsPerThreadgroup:threadgroupSize];
}
```

I tried to change the grid size putting rows on first index and cols on the second and also changing thread group Size.
I would like to obtain a Grid of R*C threads with even 1 block.

EDIT 1
I attached a photo for further explanation of what I'm trying to obtain, both cases the program gives me same error:
[Matrix, grid and block threading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4UHk.jpg)

Comment: Your threadgroup Y axis size is `threadGroupSize`, but your thread grid Y size is only `1`. What the assertion is telling you is that at least one thread group needs to fit into the grid. You can't fit an `NxN` square into a `Mx1` grid unless `N` is equal 1, and `N <= M`. If you need to discard that don't fit into your requirements, you would need to add early return to the kernel function instead of relying on the API to cull the threads for you.

Answer (score 0):

`dispatchThreads:threadsPerThreadgroup:` takes grid size and threadrgoup size. What the assertion is telling you is that at least one thread group needs to fit into the grid.

Your threadgroup Y axis size is threadGroupSize, but your thread grid Y axis size is only 1. You can't fit an NxN square into a Mx1 grid unless N is equal 1, and N <= M.

> I would like to obtain a Grid of R*C threads with even 1 block

If you need to discard that don't fit into your requirements, you would need to add early return to the kernel function instead of relying on the API to cull the threads for you. So your kernel would take your actual desired number of threads as a `[[buffer()]]` argument, then compare `[thread_position_in_grid]]` against it and just return if you don't need that thread.

Comment: I agree with your first point and now my grid is MTLSize gridSize = MTLSizeMake(rowsLength, colsLength, 1); so like in the image I attached in the EDIT 1 above. Sadly in both cases of 2x2 block or 4x4 block it tells me the same error, but I should be able to fit four 2x2 blocks into a 4x4 grid.

Comment: Could you paste the actual code you are using to try to make that work